# How to get customized tab

Tags: android, tabs

I wanted to customize my tab, which looks similar to below image.. any idea how to do..

By default, android tabs does not support set width and height in XML.. any idea how to do tabs like this

[image]

Comment: I don't see here any customization, just a default tab holder...

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic layout for a tabhost.

Here's an example: put this in the activity that will hold the tabhost and extend TabActivity after on create. Repeat for number of tabs you want. API Demos help for this basic information.

Drawable icons will be an xml file located in the drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- When selected, use white -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/white"
      android:state_selected="true" />
<!-- When not selected, use grey-->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/grey" />
```

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

// Tab 1
TabSpec tab1spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("TAB1 TITLE");
tab1spec.setIndicator("TAB1 TEXT", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab1iconhere));
Intent tab1Intent = new Intent(this, ActivityforTab1.class);
tab1spec.setContent(tab1Intent);

// Tab 2
TabSpec tab2spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("TAB2 TITLE");
tab2spec.setIndicator("TAB2 TEXT", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab2iconhere));
Intent tab2Intent = new Intent(this, ActivityforTab2.class);
tab2spec.setContent(tab2Intent);

// Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
tabHost.addTab(tab1spec); // Adding tab1
tabHost.addTab(tab2spec); // Adding tab1
```

Comment: I agree, but default tab size we can't change right.. it's fixed correct